# PhpMyAdmin 接続できません。設定が無効です。 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

PHPmyAdmin でパスワードがあっているのに関わらず、このエラーがでる場合の対処方法あったら教えてください。

[image: Phpmyadmin]

rootのパスワードはnew_passwordに設定しています。

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'new_password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
#$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'new_password';
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQLのアカウントの設定を確認してみてください。
HOST名を"127.0.0.1"として接続したい場合、MySQLアカウントとして"root@%"が存在し適切な権限が設定されている必要があります。

引用元:
[MySQLへログイン access deniedエラーの原因調査にはroot@%アカウントをチェック](https://style.potepan.com/articles/18389.html)

> MySQLでは、内部的にlocalhostと127.0.0.1は別のものとして扱われます。
> そのため、localhost指定ではログイン成功、127.0.0.1指定だとaccess deniedでログイン失敗というケースが考えられます。